# Possible to assign function parameter via destructuring?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do something like the following in js?

```
function Something( Point{PointX, PointY}   ) {
    console.log('Point', Point);
    console.log('PointX,PointY', PointX, PointY);
}
Something([1,2]);
```

If so, what would be the proper way to do that?

Comment: You either destructure or you don't. If you want the whole object, then that should be the parameter, and then destructure in a `let` or `const` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Something(Point) {
  const [PointX, PointY] = Point
  console.log('Point', Point)
  console.log('PointX,PointY', PointX, PointY)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
function Something([PointX, PointY]) {
    console.log('PointX,PointY', PointX, PointY);
}
```

You can destructure both arrays (`function([x, y]`) and objects (`function({ x, y })`).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but make sure the keys match up to do the destructuring assignment for an object, such as:

```js
function Something({x,y}) {
    console.log('PointX, PointY', x, y);
}
Something({x: 1, y: 2});
```

In terms on naming and also assigning it to the outer object, perhaps you can do something like this instead:

```js
function Something(Point) {
    const {x,y} = Point;
    console.log('Point, PointX, PointY', Point, x, y);
}
Something({x: 1, y: 2});
```